# the data did not store in the database correctly, laravel, php

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal

in my project, I wanna students to select the title, and then the title-related information will be store in the database. however, when I use modal, only the preferenceOreder be store correctly. the user_id and title id are wrong;

this is my controller: $title has property user_id and id

```
 public function titleSelect(Title $title, Request $request)
    {

        ApplicationStudent::firstOrcreate([
            'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
            'supervisor_id'=>$title->user_id,
            'title_id'=>$title->id,
            'preferenceOrder' => request('preferenceOrder')
        ]);
        return redirect('student/titleIndex');
    }
```

then, this is my blade.php

```
@foreach($titles as $title)
<td>

                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="applyModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Apply topic</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/title/{{$title->id}}/select">
                                        @csrf

                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="title_id" id="titleMk">
                                            <div class="form-check-inline">
                                                <label for="titleMark1">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="preferenceOrder" id="preferenceOrder" value="1"  checked @if($apply->has(1)) disabled @endif>
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="titleMark1">First choice</label>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <br/>

                                            <div class="form-check-inline">
                                                <label for="titleMark2">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="preferenceOrder" id="preferenceOrder" value="2" checked @if($apply->has(2)) disabled @endif>
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="titleMark2">Second Choice</label>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <br/>

                                            <div class="form-check-inline">
                                                <label for="titleMark3">
                                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="preferenceOrder" id="preferenceOrder" value="3" checked @if($apply->has(3)) disabled @endif>
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="titleMark3">Third Choice</label>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <br/>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @if(!$title->titleSelection(Auth::id())->exists() && $apply->count() < 3)
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#applyModal" >
                            Apply
                        </button>
                            @endif
                    </td>
@endforeach
```

this is my route:

```
Route::post('/title/{title}/select','StudentController@titleSelect');
```

Comment: How does your `ApplicationStudent` look like?

Comment: Check `dd($title->id)` and `dd($title->user_id)`. Show me result

Comment: sorry, this is a table which includes user_id, supervisor_id, title_id,

Comment: I find that whenever I click which row, the title_id is 4, what I can do

Comment: Do you check `dd($title->user_id)`?

Comment: yes, I check it, and all is the same title_id, but I have used foreach in it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q: the user_id and title id are wrong;**

A:

This is a common mistake while working with modal in Foreach..

For modals the id should be unique, where as for the above modal the id's for all modal will be `id="applyModal"`.

The first value will be loaded and will be repeated there after. No new Values will be populated

By adding unique Id the modal will be populated with the correspinding results..

Note: In html page there shouldn't be no similar Id's. It will throw you an error..

Try updating it like

```
<!-- Modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="applyModal-{{$title->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
....
</div>
```

Same Id should be used while invoking the modal..

**This is how I do**

```
@foreach($title as $title)

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal-{{$title->id}}">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-{{$title->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for posting an answer rather than a comment, but I can't comment or up-vote

However, You should use a foreach on the models as well. as suggested by mightyteja.

I would suggest using Livewire if you want something more robust and javascripty, it is actually easy to use

Another note. I would recommend naming your routes!

For example:

```
Route::post('/title/{title}/select','StudentController@titleSelect')->name('student.title.select');
```

Now in your views you can simply do the following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('student.title.select', $title->id) }}">
```

Or for multiple uri variables:

```
{{ route('name', ['id' => $model->id, 'name' => $model->name]) }}
```

I recommend this because if for some reason you changed the route. You don't have to change it everywhere in the views (easier to maintain). The naming feature is actually amazing.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your advice, I realize that it is very useful and easy to maintain in the future.